# Is there a way to get the NSPanel a button is belonging to from the sender object ?

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way to get the NSPanel a button is belonging to from the sender object ?

```
- (void)closeButtonClicked:(id)sender {
   ... something like [sender getPanel]...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSButton` is an `NSView` subclass, `NSView` has a window property which gives access to the `NSWindow` it is in. If the button is in an `NSPanel` then its window property would contain that panel (`NSPanel` is a subclass of `NSWindow`). So something like

```
NSPanel* panel = (NSPanel*)[(NSButton*)sender window];
```

should get you the panel. I would check that they are of the right kind of class for safety.